# dynamic/variable table name C# sqlclient

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

I have  database tables that dynamically gets created.
They all have the same name but with a unique ID at the end of the name like for example myTable1, myTable2 and so on.

I have these IDs but the question is how should my SQL look like in C# using sqlclient?

For example:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable"+id;
```

Works but is still open for SQL injections

I've also tried:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable@id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
```

But does not work since the sql reads the table name as myTable@id not for example myTable1

Is there a way to insert parameters for the table name?

Comment: You **cannot** parametrize your table (or column) name. If you want to do that, you need to concatenate together your SQL statement (which always opens the risk of SQL injection)

Comment: Just change `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id)` into `sql = sql.Replace("@Id", id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Regular SQL* can't have parameters on field names or table names, just on values.

Take a look at [`Dynamic SQL`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) instead.

- [`SELECT * FROM @tablename`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table)

Answer (score 0):

I think using column names in this particular query may do the job .

```
string sql = "SELECT colName1, colName2 , colname ......FROM myTable"+id;
```